# Disable Form clearing TextFormField after submitting

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to disable Form clearing TextFormField after submitting? I have created simple login form with two TextFormField (email and password) which log in to firebase. I have chosen Form because of validator feature. All works nice apart from when the form is submitted with wrong credential then all TextFormFields are empty and I have to type them all over again which is ok on password but quite weird on email

Here is the code

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
String _email;
String _password;
final Status status = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context).status;

void submitForm() {
  if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    return;
  }
  _formKey.currentState.save();
  try {
    Provider.of<UserRepository>(context, listen: false)
        .signIn(_email, _password, context);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}

return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
    child: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            initialValue: _email,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            autofocus: true,
            decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Email'),
            validator: emailValidator,
            onSaved: (value) {
              _email = value.trim();
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          TextFormField(
              obscureText: true,
              decoration:
                  kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Password'),
              onSaved: (value) {
                _password = value.trim();
              }),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          RoundedButton(
            title: 'Login',
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            onPressed: () {
              submitForm();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

I have tried to initialised the email field with _email variable but even the variable is null after submitting. I've looked everywhere in documentation but didn't find any solution for this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `StatefulWidget` .

because in `StatelessWidget` the build method is getting called for many reasons like (screen rotation, animations, scrolling) .

Comment: I didn't want to use statefull widget because I'm using provider to navigate through pages but changing it to stageful widget helped it. However now even password field stay unchanged which I don't like it so I have to find a way how to clear it :)

Comment: Define  _email , _password outside build method

Comment: Thanks Mohamed. I tried that but then I changed it back to stateless widget as I described in my answer below. Thing is I'm using provider for managing my states so converting login page to statefull doesn't make any sense. As I described below I'm now storing the email value in my provider and using it in initialValue property of TextFormField

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it doesn't clear the fields on my side.
Anyway, the best practices would be to :

- convert LoginScreen to a StatefulWidget
- move the variables and function **outside** of the build method
- use TextEditingController instead of String for _email and _password

This might help. Keep in mind that the build method gets called **every time** the widget is rendered.

*PS : In a StatefulWidget, change the state in a `setState((){})` for the widget to rebuild.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to save your email.

Comment: Thanks. It make sense to store the email however I've got many other forms which I don't want to clear on exception and storing all of them just for this purpose doesn't sound right

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answer however I managed to make it without converting my Login screen to StateFull widget. Basically as I mention I use provider for navigating through screen (authenticated, non authenticated) so I'm saving my initial value of the email there and then just pick them after throwing exception when the stateless screen is rebuild

Here is peace of my provider code

```
class UserRepository with ChangeNotifier {
 FirebaseAuth _auth;
 FirebaseUser _user;
 Status _status = Status.Uninitialized;
 Map<String, String> _initialValue = {'email': ''};
 .
 .
Status get status => _status;
FirebaseUser get user => _user;
String get initialEmail => _initialValue['email'];
.
.
  Future<bool> signIn(
  String email, String password, BuildContext context) async {
  try {
  _status = Status.Authenticating;
  notifyListeners();
  _initialValue['email'] = email;
  await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  return true;
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
  _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
  exceptionAlertDialog(context, e.message);
  notifyListeners();
  return false;
 }
}
```

and here is the textfield from my login screen

```
  TextFormField(
            initialValue: Provider.of<UserRepository>(context).initialEmail,
            autocorrect: false,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            autofocus: true,
            decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Email'),
            validator: emailValidator,
            onSaved: (value) {
              _email = value.trim();
            },
          ),
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing it but it works. I'm trying to use Statefull widgets as low as possible and it sound bit strange to convert my login screen to statefull widget just for this purpose